# Is there a specialized algorithm, faster than quicksort, to reorder data ACEGBDFH?

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, optimization, language-agnostic

I have some data coming from the hardware. Data comes in blocks of 32 bytes, and there are potentially millions of blocks. Data blocks are scattered in two halves the following way (a letter is one block):

```
A C E G I K M O B D F H J L N P
```

or if numbered

```
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
```

First all blocks with even indexes, then the odd blocks. Is there a specialized algorithm to reorder the data correctly (alphabetical order)?

The constraints are mainly on space. I don't want to allocate another buffer to reorder: just one more block. But I'd also like to keep the number of moves low: a simple quicksort would be O(NlogN). Is there a faster solution in O(N) for this special reordering case?

Comment: Sorting can not be done in O(n) complexity.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: In general case, it is true, but this data is partially sorted already

Comment: when you say "always the following way" do you mean that the ordering is always as given - that the first block is first, the second is ninth, the third second, etc?  if so, then surely you can just write the code to re-arrange them explicitly?

Comment: You really need to explain how your data is partially sorted. Is it just divided into two sorted halves? Or do the two halves always contain odd/even elements respectively?

Comment: Ok, I seem to have the "millions of blocks" part, suggesting that there is some more at play here, than I assumed in my answer. For clarifications: If there were 18 Blocks instead of 16, where would the additional two blocks go? Is 18 Blocks possible in your case at all, or would this be forbidden. How I understand this now after re-reading, is that you are receiving in the pattern: `Odd numbered block` `even numbered blocks` and not a fixed pattern of 16 blocks `A C E G I K M O B D F H J L N P`, maybe repeating itself as I first assumed. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I'm always receiving first the `odd blocks` followed by the `even blocks`. If I receive one million blocks, then I'll get first half a million odd blocks, followed by half a million even blocks. In the end I want to have all of them reordered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this data is always in the same order, sorting in the classical sense is not needed at all. You do not need any comparisons, since you already know in advance which of two given data points.

Instead you can produce the permutation on the data directly. If you transform this into cyclic form, this will tell you exactly which swaps to do, to transform the permuted data into ordered data.

Here is an example for your data:

```
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 1 3  5  7  9 11 13 15
0 1 2 3 4 5  6  7  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Now calculate the inverse (I'll skip this step, because I am lazy here, assume instead the permutation I have given above actually is the inverse already).

Here is the cyclic form:

```
(0)(1 8 4 2)(3 9 12 6)(5 10)(7 11 13 14)(15)
```

So if you want to reorder a sequence structured like this, you would do

```
# first cycle
# nothing to do

# second cycle
swap 1 8
swap 8 4
swap 4 2

# third cycle
swap 3 9
swap 9 12
swap 12 6

# so on for the other cycles
```

If you would have done this for the inverse instead of the original permutation, you would get the correct sequence with a proven minimal number of swaps.

**EDIT**:

For more details on something like this, see the chapter on Permutations in TAOCP for example.

Comment: But what is the point, as calculating the cyclic form of a permutation is O(N^2)? Or am I not familiar with an O(N) algorithm? -1 until you elaborate. :D Can you somehow generate it in O(N) for arbitrary N for the specific form his data has?

Comment: Then now, how can I compute the permutation for any number of blocks N (N is even) without using lots of memory?

Comment: @svinja as the OP writes, the data comes in `always` in the way he described. Precalculating for arbitrary N was neither requested nor required.

Comment: @svinja Ok, forget it :-) Stupid me. How could I understand the `always` in the question like it was meant like `always`...

Comment: It comes in that form (ordered odds, then ordered evens) but it can be millions of blocks long, not just 16. That is the way I understand it at least, otherwise "millions of blocks" doesn't make sense.

Comment: `Permutations in TAOCP`, what does `TAOCP` mean? where can I see this?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: TAOCP:="The Art of Computer Programming" by Donald Knuth. Permutations are covered in Volume 1. You can find it here: http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Programming-Volumes-1-4A-Boxed/dp/0321751043/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336645446&sr=8-1

Comment: @LiKao gosh! I should have guessed. In fact I have this volume but never read it.

Answer (score 3):

So you have data coming in in a pattern like

a<sub>0</sub> a<sub>2</sub> a<sub>4</sub>...a<sub>14</sub> a<sub>1</sub> a<sub>3</sub> a<sub>5</sub>...a<sub>15</sub>

and you want to have it sorted to

b<sub>0</sub> b<sub>1</sub> b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>15</sub>

With some reordering the permutation can be written like:

a<sub>0</sub> -> b<sub>0</sub>

a<sub>8</sub> -> b<sub>1</sub>
a<sub>1</sub> -> b<sub>2</sub>
a<sub>2</sub> -> b<sub>4</sub>
a<sub>4</sub> -> b<sub>8</sub>

a<sub>9</sub> -> b<sub>3</sub>
a<sub>3</sub> -> b<sub>6</sub>
a<sub>6</sub> -> b<sub>12</sub>
a<sub>12</sub> -> b<sub>9</sub>

a<sub>10</sub> -> b<sub>5</sub>
a<sub>5</sub> -> b<sub>10</sub>

a<sub>11</sub> -> b<sub>7</sub>
a<sub>7</sub> -> b<sub>14</sub>
a<sub>14</sub> -> b<sub>13</sub>
a<sub>13</sub> -> b<sub>11</sub>

a<sub>15</sub> -> b<sub>15</sub>

So if you want to sort in place it with only one block additional space in a temporary `t`, this could be done in O(1) with

```
t = a8;   a8 = a4;  a4 = a2;  a2 = a1;  a1 = t

t = a9;   a9 = a12; a12= a6;  a6 = a3;  a9 = t

t = a10; a10 = a5;  a5 = t

t = a11; a11 = a13; a13 = a14; a14 = a7; a7 = t
```

Edit:
The general case (for N != 16), if it is solvable in O(N), is actually an interesting question. I suspect the cycles always start with a prime number which satisfies `p < N/2 && N mod p != 0` and the indices have a recurrence like i<sub>n+1</sub> = 2i<sub>n</sub> mod N, but I am not able to prove it. If this is the case, deriving an O(N) algorithm is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, that's another way to write LiKao's answer. Now, how can I do this for any number of blocks N (N is even)?

Comment: @drhirsh: Ok, your way derives the swaps directly without calculating the inverse first. And you do not need a large number of temporaries like I did, by swapping in opposite direction. I guess I have to take some more time refining my first ideas next time. +1 for this nice refinement.

Answer (score 1):

maybe i'm misunderstanding, but if the order is always *identical* to the one given then you can "pre-program" (ie avoiding all comparisons) the optimum solution (which is going to be the one that has the minimmum number of swaps to move from the string given to ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP and which, for something this small, you can work out by hand - see LiKao's answer).

Comment: I do not see how the edit distance comes in here. The edit distance usually deals with delete/insert/replace type of changes from one sequence to another, not permutations. If you need permutation, this is what you should use.

Comment: oh, sorry, i though it included swapping characters.  will update.

Comment: At least the standard edit distance doesn't include swaps. Maybe there is a specialised version. If you can find one, I would be really interested in the changes to the algorithm to get it to consider swaps.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier for me to label your set with numbers:

0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15

Start from the 14 and move all even numbers to place (8 swaps). You will get this:

0 1 2 9 4 6 13 8 3 10 7 12 11 14 15

Now you need another 3 swaps (9 with 3, 7 with 13, 11 with 13 moved from 7).

A total of 11 swaps. Not a general solution, but it could give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can also view the intended permutation as a shuffle of the address-bits `abcd <-> dabc' (with abcd the individual bits of the index) Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROTATE(v,n,i) (((v)>>(i)) | (((v) & ((1u <<(i))-1)) << ((n)-(i))))

/******************************************************/
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
unsigned i,a,b;

for (i=0; i < 16; i++) {
        a = ROTATE(i,4,1);
        b = ROTATE(a,4,3);

        fprintf(stdout,"i=%u a=%u b=%u\n", i, a, b);
        }

return 0;
}

/******************************************************/
```

Answer (score -2):

That was [count sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) I believe